# ProgressBar not showing in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

I am loading list in `ListView` using `AsyncTask` by showing `ProgressBar`. But in my code the `ProgressBar` is now showing. Cant understand the problem.

I used the same code as in slidenerd but in the video code works but my code doesn't seem to work.

[Video Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dVwR5Gpw1_E)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;
    String[] items = {"Ankush", "Kapoor", "Amit", "Kumar", "Shirshak", "Tillu", "Mishra", "Sudeep", "Dey", "Ayon",
            "Ankush", "Kapoor", "Amit", "Kumar", "Shirshak", "Tillu", "Mishra", "Sudeep", "Dey", "Ayon",
            "Ankush", "Kapoor", "Amit", "Kumar", "Shirshak", "Tillu", "Mishra", "Sudeep", "Dey", "Ayon",
            "Ankush", "Kapoor", "Amit", "Kumar", "Shirshak", "Tillu", "Mishra", "Sudeep", "Dey", "Ayon"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new ArrayList<String>());
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        new JSONTask().execute();
    }

    public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {

        private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
        private int count = 0;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            adapter = (ArrayAdapter<String>) listView.getAdapter();
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
            setProgressBarVisibility(true);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            for (String i : items) {
                publishProgress(i);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            adapter.add(values[0]);
            count++;
            setProgress((int) (((double) count / items.length) * 10000));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
            setProgressBarVisibility(false);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Done!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you want to try to use the ProgressDialog instead? Just create it and call .show() or .hide();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(boolean)) of `setProgressBarVisibility()` and `setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility()`:

> This method was deprecated in API level 24.
>
> No longer supported
>   starting in API 21.

You should use a `ProgressDialog` instead.

Answer (score 0):

you should use simple `ProgressDialog`
for example :

```
ProgressDialog myPd = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Please wait", "Uploading Database to Cloud...", true);
myPd.setCancelable(false);
```